# I want to develop a web based app which will have a

Tags: web, responsive-design, interactive

I want to develop a web based app which will have following functionalities
 1. A login
 2. After authenticated login, users will be redirected to another web page and there will be a background image.
 3. This is the most crucial part, I want users to be able to click on the background image and draw a line on the image which can be saved later. An example of that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MilBA.png)

Any ideas which is the best language to implant this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js + jquery would do this. Google "Nodejs Draw Line" and the first few websites already have the code.

Comment: And if I want to store those lines drawn for later use, which db you would suggest best?

Comment: MySQL should be fine.